# SQL Query is updated when user updates Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have an excel document that I want to link to an SQL query. In the excel document I have a list of item numbers. Whenever an item number gets changed I want the sql query to query that list of item numbers and return an output. Basically I want the excel sheet to use the Item Number as a parameter for the database item numbers ? The excel item numbers are updated daily.

Comment: You can't really do that without adding a separate query table for each item number within your spreadsheet. You could, however, add a query table that looks up the information you need for ALL item numbers, then do a lookup to join the item numbers in your excel sheet to the information from the query table.

Comment: I have too much data to do a query table I need to make the item numbers a parameter of the query

Comment: Well, the only other solution I can think of is to set up a connection to the database, loop through each of the item numbers in your spreadsheet, pass a query for each one, and return the results of that query next to it, but I wouldn't be able to help you with that without more info on the database and your spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you provide a mock example?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this is a mock example for what you are trying to do. With no knowledge of your database or spreadsheet, I can't guarantee that any of this will even work. At the very least, it will require you to make some adjustments before you can use it.

With that in mind, I have commented on various parts of the code to let you know what is going on there. The sections that have a `***` are areas that you may want to change. The sections with `###` are areas that you will **HAVE** to change for it to work for you.

This code assumes that you have a list of item numbers in column A of sheet 1, that each item number will only return one record, and that there are no blank cells in your list of item numbers.

```
Sub GrabItemInfo()
Dim objADO As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim strConn As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim errNum As Long

'open a connection to the database
'### change the properties for the connection to suit your needs
strConn = "DSN=DSNName; DBQ=Database; UID=Username; PWD=Password"
objADO.Open strConn
objCmd.ActiveConnection = objADO
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'errNum is the row that the error log will start on
'***change errNum to change which row it starts on
errNum = 1
'***changeRowNum here to change which row to start on
RowNum = 1
'start the loop
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNum, 1) = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    '### change the sql to whatever you need
    '*** change the cells section if you're not using the first column
    strSQL = "SELECT [field] FROM [table] WHERE ItemNum = " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
    objCmd.CommandText = strSQL
    Set objRecSet = objCmd.Execute
    'pastes results from query into the cell next to the item number
    '***change the cells section if you want to use a different column
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNum, 2).CopyFromRecordset objRecSet
    'clear out the recordset before the loops starts again
    Set objRecSet = Nothing
    'put the item number, error number, and error description on the second sheet of the work book
    '***change the sheet number to put it on another sheet if you're already using the second
    If Err > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(errNum, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(errNum, 2).Value = Err.Number
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(errNum, 3).Value = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    'raise the value for the row for the next iteration
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

'clear out the connection
Set objADO = Nothing
Set objRecSet = Nothing
Set objCmd = Nothing

End Sub
```

For more information on connection strings, I recommend http://www.connectionstrings.com
It's a great resource to use for figuring out what kind of connection string you need. Connections strings can be...tricky...sometimes, and this really helps.

If you need any resources for SQL, I would recommend http://www.w3schools.com/sql
They have a good introduction to it there. Past that, get a good reference book, find a mentor, join forums(or Q&A sites like this one), etc. If you look into the SQL tag on this site, there is more information, along with some recommended resources as well.

Good luck.